# Namespace Alias in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I apologize if this is duplicate; please guide me to the right directions.

I know we can create class aliases in Laravel from `/config/app.php`. However trying to create namespace aliases using the same method fails.

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [
    ...

    /*
    *    My custom namespace aliases
    */
    'MyNamespace' => 'App\Models\MyNamespace',

    ],
```

Testing this in thinker returns the following results:

```
>> new \MyNamespace\MyClass();

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyNamespace/MyClass' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

---

Do you know a way to create namespace alias in Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your code PSR-4 compatible and put it in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "MyNamespace\\": "src/MyNameSpace",
    }
},
```

Then run `composer dumpautoload`. So long as you stick to the convention of subfolders being namespaces, your classes will autoload.

`src/MyNamespace/SomeClass.php` would have `namespace MyNamespace;` and `class SomeClass`.

`src/MyNamespace/Something/SomethingElse.php` would have `namespace MyNamespace\Something;` and `class SomethingElse`.